# Slider not working with touch input

Tags: wpf, xaml, slider, touch

I have this Slider in WPF :

```
<Slider x:Name="SizeSlider" IsManipulationEnabled="True" Width="100" Minimum="1" Maximum="10" Value="1" ValueChanged="SizeSlider_ValueChanged"></Slider>
```

I can drag the slider's cursor with the mouse, but not with touch input.

What do I need to do in order to use the slider with touch input ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So I found the solution, thanks to the link provided by Agentlien.

In XAML, add a TouchDown attribute :

```
<Slider x:Name="SizeSlider" Width="100" Minimum="1" Maximum="10" Value="1" ValueChanged="SizeSlider_ValueChanged" TouchDown="SizeSlider_TouchDown"/>
```

(I also removed the IsManipulationEnabled property as it is not necessary here)

In C# code-behind :

```
private void SizeSlider_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
{
    // Things you want to do everytime slider's value change
    // For example :
    _brushSize = e.NewValue;
}


private void SizeSlider_TouchDown(object sender, TouchEventArgs e)
{
    // Mark event as handled
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Like this, the slider can be used with both mouse and touch input.

Comment: Seeing as this solution is what fixed your problem, you should choose it as accepted answer, so people know where to look.

Comment: Thanks to remind me ! I couldn't before because I had to wait 1 more day :) and thanks again for your help !

Comment: You are very welcome. :) It's always nice being able to help. I just happened to be struggling with a similar problem when my Google search brought both the link I provided and a link to this question. So, I figured I'd best connect the two.

Answer (score 3):

It looks to me like you may be suffering from the issue described here:

http://nui.joshland.org/2010/04/why-wont-wpf-controls-work-with-touch.html

In short: **`IsManipulationEnabled`** affects whether the touch generates a mouse event or not if the touch event is not handled, so you need to make sure to handle the correct event.

Comment: Thank you ! With the link you provided I was able to solve my problem. But it wasn't something about the IsManipulationEnabled property. I'll add my own answer, but as yours was also helpful I'll upvote it as soon as I can (>15 rep).

Comment: @MichaëlPolla You're over 15 now.

Comment: @Undo : done ! ...funny nickname by the way :-D At first I didn't understand why I was able to "Undo" a comment... hehe